# How to handle ECONNRESET, Connection reset by peer

Tags: javascript, node.js

A lot of my node.js processes are crashing with the ECONNRESET error. Here's the output I can see:

```
node.js:50
    throw e;
    ^
Error: ECONNRESET, Connection reset by peer
    at Client._readImpl (net:320:14)
    at IOWatcher.callback (net:470:24)
    at node.js:607:9
```

Does anyone know how to handle this? It's not a very useful stack trace so I have no idea where it's happening. Should I just wrap any and all access to a remote source via http with a try/catch block? Or is there a better way?

In general I don't care if this does happen or if some task does not get completed because of this. What I do care about is that the process should just shrug it off and work on the next task.

Comment: What are your module dependencies?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to attach to the error Event for your socket. If you don't, then the default action is to throw an exception when an error occurs.

```
socket.on('error', function (exc) {
    sys.log("ignoring exception: " + exc);
});
```

Comment: This resides on the server side right? Inside the .on("connect", function(socket){ //listen to err here })

Comment: Finally! You have no idea how long it took to find this.