# Should ECONNRESET just be handled?

Tags: node.js

Using the Node `net` package I'm currently getting a lot of `ECONNERESET` errors in my application; there is a lot of information online about how to handle them, but are these errors something that should just be handled or fixed? How would you go about finding the issue and fixing it because the stack trace is not that helpful?

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1050:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:582:26)
    [stack]: 'Error: read ECONNRESET\n    at exports._errnoException 
    (util.js:1050:11)\n    at TCP.onread (net.js:582:26)',
    [message]: 'read ECONNRESET',
    code: 'ECONNRESET',
    errno: 'ECONNRESET',
    syscall: 'read'
```

Comment: Your question is basically a duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088222/how-to-handle-econnreset-connection-reset-by-peer

Comment: @robertklep - Is this a duplicate? They have outright said they want to ignore it, I'm not sure that actually answers whether it is safe to ignore..

Comment: That's why I didn't close it as a duplicate, although it does show how to handle them, in terms of catching them and showing a message. There isn't much else you can do (the error means that "the other side" has closed the connection, which isn't an uncommon event when dealing with network connections).

Comment: I appreciate that @robertklep; I am already handling them (using that exact method) and logging them onto the screen. I was just a little concerned that suppressing them could be dangerous if there is something untoward going on.